# How to combine partition created by failed Ubuntu installation with that created by a subsequent installation

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 (dual boot with windows 7), but the installation failed. I tried again and was successful, but then realised that I still had the partition from the previous attempt. I have tried to use gparted to shrink this partition in order to expand that of the successful installation, but it won't allow me to do so (resize option greyed out). I also tried deleting all the items contained therein - they no longer show in nautilus, but the free space has not increased). How can I combine these two partitions?

Comment: Hadn't unmounted drive - hence the greyed out option. Still not sure how to combine. Comes up with message "You have queued an operation to move the start sector of partition /dev/sda5.  Failure to boot is most likely to occur if you move the GNU/Linux partition containing /boot, or if you move the Windows system partition C:.
You can learn how to repair the boot configuration in the GParted FAQ.
http://gparted.org/faq.php"

Comment: Can you post an image of what you see in gparted? You should be able to delete the unneeded partition and resize the good one (as long as both are unmounted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Run gparted from a live cd.
- Delete the partition you do not want.
- Resize the other partition to take up all of the available free
  space.
- Reinstall grub (unless you have /boot on the first disk partition)
- Reboot